# ¿Es posible pedirle al usuario un input pero cuando este lo dá, hacer que el input no se muestre más en pantalla?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Por ejemplo si se tiene el siguiente código quiero saber si se puede dejar de mostrar el input que el usuario dió para "P1" cuando se le pide el de "P2",ya que la idea del código es que el usuario que responde a "P2" adivine la palabra elegida por "P1" pero no tendría sentido si el input de "P1" se sigue mostrando.

```
from random import*
p1=input("Player #1,enter a word: ")
def function(p1):
    l=[x for x in p1]
    shuffle(l)
    print("".join(l))
    p2=input("Player #2,try to guess the word: ")
    count=1
    while p1.lower()!=p2.lower():
       p2=input("You didn´t guess it, keep trying: ")
       count+=1
    if p2.lower()==p1.lower():
       print("Congratulations you guessed it right in "+str(count)+" attempts")
function(p1)
```

Comment: Hola Felka ¿Podrías dar algo más de contexto? ¿Dónde usas esos inputs?¿En un ciclo? Podrías simplemente inicializar la variable `x` a `None` y meter el `input` para `x` en un condicional  `if  x is None:` Pero posiblemente exista una mejor solución, pero se necesitaría poner esas líneas en el contexto en el que tu las usas para poder contestar en base a ello. Un saludo.

Comment: Creo que lo que buscas es el módulo [`getpass`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/getpass.html)

Comment: Si lo que quieres es que la entrada del usuario no se muestre en pantalla mientras el usuario la ingresa (típicamente para ingresar una contraseña y que esta no sea leída por terceros) `getpass` es lo que buscas como comenta abulafia, Ahora releído creo que lo que puedes querer es limpiar la terminal para que el input anterior desaparezca, en ese caso `os.system("clear")` en linux   o `os.system("cls")` en Windows es lo que buscas. De todas formas aclara la pregunta por favor, no termina de quedar muy claro que pretendes conseguir y no tiene sentido que andemos elucubrando.

Comment: Listo, ya especifiqué el contexto de mi código,espero que la situación se les aclare.

Comment: Estuve intentando el os.system("cls") pero lo único que pasa es que me muestra una flecha hacia arriba. Probablemente es que no sé en que lugar del código ponerlo y en internet no viene mucha info al respecto

Answer (score 0):

Lo que necesitas son los [códigos de escape de ANSI](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%B3digo_escape_ANSI).

Si lees la documentación enlazada verás que el código de escape `[K` permite borrar la línea entera.
Sin embargo, cuando el usuario ha introducido un input, ha pulsado enter.
Por lo tanto el cursor no estará en la línea que quieres borrar, sino en la línea siguiente.
Así que hay que usar otro código de escape para subir a la línea de arriba antes de hacer el borrado.
Ello lo haremos con `[1A`.
El número `1` indica la cantidad de filas hacia arriba que nos desplazaremos.

En Python para usar los caracteres de escape los debes escribir con el prefijo `\033[`.

Aplicado a tu caso concreto, el borrado lo haremos antes de entrar al bucle:

```
p1 = input("Player #1, enter a word: ")
print('\033[1A' + '\033[K', end='')
```

Esto funcionará, pero ten en cuenta que también borrará la frase *Player #1, nter a word:*.
Si no quisieras borrar esta frase, te recomiendo que añadas un salto de línea.
Así el usuario no escribirá justo a continuación, sino una línea más abajo.
Cuando ejecutes el borrado, sólo borrarás lo que haya escrito el usuario.

Ten en cuenta que este es un sistema bastante frágil.
Si el usuario escribiera más caracteres de los que caben en una línea de consola, este sistema no funcionará.